# Draggable and zoomable AsyncImage does not trigger long press gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture-recognition

I have an `AsyncImage` that is zoomable via `MagnifyGesture` and drawable via a view modifier. Dragging and zooming works as expected. But now I want to show an overlay via `onLongPressGesture`, but this doesn't trigger. If I remove `.draggable` it works. How can I fix it?

```
public struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewState: ViewState
    @State private var showAltText: Bool = false
    @State private var currentZoom = 0.0
    @State private var totalZoom   = 1.0
    
    public init(viewState vs:ViewState) {
        viewState = vs
    }
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                if viewState.selectedComicStrip != nil {
                    AsyncImage(url: viewState.selectedComicStrip!.imageURL) { image in
                        image.resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 600)
                    } placeholder: {
                        Text("placeholder").frame(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 600)
                    }
                    .draggable()
                    .scaleEffect(currentZoom + totalZoom)
                    .gesture(
                        MagnifyGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                currentZoom = value.magnification - 1
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                totalZoom += currentZoom
                                currentZoom = 0
                            }
                    )
                    .onLongPressGesture {
                        showAltText.toggle()
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                            showAltText = false
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("placeholder")
                }
            }
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showAltText, content: {
            ZStack {
                Color.black.opacity(0.8)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Text(viewState.selectedComicStrip!.altText)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .padding()
            }
        })
        .padding()
    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082240/106435
struct DraggableView: ViewModifier {
    @State var offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { value in
                    self.offset.x += value.location.x - value.startLocation.x
                    self.offset.y += value.location.y - value.startLocation.y
                })
            .offset(x: offset.x, y: offset.y)
    }
}

extension View {
    func draggable() -> some View {
        return modifier(DraggableView())
    }
}
```

Comment: with "Drawing" you mean dragging, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-two-gestures-recognize-at-the-same-time-using-simultaneousgesture) Hacking with Swift post and a few others, SwiftUI will only trigger one gesture at a time by default.
However, as far as I can tell from the docs, the exact behavior is undefined in general:

> When you add multiple gestures to your app’s view hierarchy, *you need to decide how the gestures interact with each other.* You use gesture composition to define the order SwiftUI recognizes gestures. [[SwiftUI docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing-swiftui-gestures), emphasis mine.]

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284994/swiftui-how-to-handle-both-tap-long-press-of-button) SO question, you could try a couple things:

1. Wrap the long-press gesture in a [`simultaneousGesture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/simultaneousgesture) modifier. (Probably the most robust approach, suggested by the docs.)
2. Set a positive `minimumDistance` on the `DragGesture`. (That way, it doesn't trigger immediately and preclude the long-press gesture from triggering too.)
3. Add the `onLongPressGesture` before the `DragGesture`. (Probably the most fragile option.)